# Display CVPixelBuffer with YUV422 format on iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, core-video

I'm using openGL ES to display CVPixelBuffers on iOS. The openGL pipeline uses the fast texture upload APIs (CVOpenGLESTextureCache*). When running my app on the actual device the display is great but on the simulator it's not the same (I understand that those APIs don't work on the simulator).

I noticed that, when using the simulator, the pixel format is kCVPixelFormatType_422YpCbCr8 and I'm trying to extract the Y and UV components and use the glTexImage2D to upload but, I'm getting some incorrect results. For now I'm concentrating on the Y component only, and the result looks like the image is half of the expected width and is duplicated - if it makes sense.

I would like to know from some one that has successfully displayed YUV422 video frames on iOS simulator if I'm on the right track and/or if I can get some pointers on how to solve my problem.

Thanks!